# Panel not allowing additions?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm trying to make something appear on the GUI. Anything at this point. But it seems the panel itself is not being put onto the frame. Why?

```
public class Gui  {
public JFrame frame;
public JPanel panel;
public JPanel input;
public JButton btn1;
public JLabel label;
public BorderLayout border;

private ImageIcon iconURL;

public void guiSet(){
    frame = new JFrame("Java y u do this");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/img/icon.png")));

    //Panels
    panel = new JPanel();
    input = new JPanel();
    //Buttons
    btn1 = new JButton("Y u no show up");
    JCheckBox cb2;
    cb2 = new JCheckBox("YO HOME DAWG");

    //Addtions
    frame.add(panel);

    panel.add(btn1);
    panel.add(cb2);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  That source would need imports and a `main(String[])` to launch the existing GUI.

Comment: `frame.setVisible(true);` should be last, immediately preceded by `frame.pack()`..

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

Calling `setVisible` on the frame before you finished creating the frame...

### The Solutions...

1. Call `setVisible` last
2. Call `revalidate` on the `JFrame` after you've added content to it...

Comment: *"2. Call revalidate on the JFrame after you've added content to it..."*  It should be noted that very, *very* few GUIs should be adding components after that part of the GUI has 1st been made visible.  Most of the 'obvious' uses would be better served by a `CardLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the set visible was at the front? Don't know how that works...

Comment: If you can provide a solution, I'll give you a +1

Comment: move frame.setVisible(true); to the end of the gui() construct

Comment: Tell the OP not me, put it in your answer ;)